# Load balance two ADSL connections Centos 7

Tags: load-balancing, centos7, failover, bonding

I have centos 7 server working as a gateway for my network with three LAN cards and two internet connections from different ISPs , i want to combine the two connections and balance the network load between them  .. I've tried bonding and it didn't work for me well and all the tutorials i watched about load balancing in Linux wasn't good .
any ideas !?

Comment: What do you mean with "load balance"?

Comment: I want to share  the two connections side by side to my network and make load balancing between them i think it means that all the network traffic will be shared between them to increase speed and availability

Comment: Well, if you refer to "doing round-robin for your traffic" on both lines using "load balance", then, I'm afraid, this needs more than bonding at your place. You would have to setup a remote point as well, to do bonding over there, so your traffic originates from one source IP. You could do this via a publicly reachable machine somewhere and tunneling your traffic to this point. Or you could set up a stateful firewall which could keep track of your connections and ensures that...

Comment: ...traffic to the same destination is send over one line. Besides: I'm unsure if you know how routing and TCP/IP works, but maybe it would be good to some research first.

Comment: Yeah .. I'm trying to learn by doing ... and I am not talking here about bonding I've tried bonding and it's not the best solution here am doing some researches at this time and i can really use any help to know where to start at least ... after all .. Thank u

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/141462/is-there-a-sensible-way-of-teaming-two-adsl-connections).

Comment: Maybe have a look as well [at this .pdf](http://wiki.imagestream.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=Special:PdfPrint&page=OpenVPN_Load_Balancing) to get an idea how you could build something like this.

Comment: Yeah that's what i was talking about thanks for your help i will try this and i hope it works

Comment: You can also consider this: http://www.zeroshell.org/load-balancing-failover/ It's a linux distro in its own right, but poking around may give you some ideas how they do it. More routing examples here: http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html

Comment: OK .. now i used [This](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html) guide and it actually worked well on the server and it can balance between the two ISP's i disabled firewalld and configured everything through iptables but the only problem now that the server can't handle dns requests and i can't browse any website or download anything from any client side , i can ping any ip successfully ...

Answer (score 0):

This is not what bonding is for.

You need policy routing.